# How does bind(2) choose a network device?

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface, socket

**Background**

I'm looking to write kernel-space implementations of a non-IP network protocol and associated network device driver (non-ethernet hardware). I found some resources on developing the protocol and the driver, though I'm having difficulty understanding how to associate sockets using my protocol with my driver.

The aim is to have it working such that a program in userspace would only need to call `bind(socket(AF_TERRIBLE_IDEA, ...), ...);` and be good to go.

The aim is to get more familiar developing for kernel-space simultaneously, so moving to userspace is not ideal.

**Question**

when a *bind* call is made, how does the kernel know which device (and therefore device driver) to associate a socket to?

Comment: `bind(2)` doesn't bind to interfaces; it binds to addresses. eg for TCP sockets, it's at the TCP layer, which is above the IP layer, which is above the physical layer.  The physical interface isn't relevant to `bind(2)`.

Comment: @StephenHarris Where does the association occur then?

Comment: It doesn't.  The physical driver knows what packets are addressed to it's MAC address.  It passes that up the stack to the protocol driver, which may pass it further up the stack.  Finally a match on address/port is made.  This is far away from the physical interface.

Comment: @StephenHarris How is this done before any packets are received? Say there is a system with 2 NICs and I bind to an address before sending a packet. What dictates which NIC the packet comes out of?

Comment: Clients, typically, don't bind.  Servers bind.  Now a client _can_ bind, if they want the source to be from a specific value (eg port or IP).  But this doesn't impact traffic.  The `bind` has no impact on the interface use.  It's the routing table to the destination determines where the packets go, and so what interface the traffic uses.

Comment: Basically, you, as author of AF_TERRIBLE_IDEA get to decide what interface is used.  Not the application, but the protocol.

Comment: Almost all of the time, a user program calls bind on an inet socket with either 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 or the first address in the list of addresses returned by `gethostbyname(gethostname())`, which ought to be the address of one of the interfaces. But you can bind to any address at all, even if it's not currently an interface's address and will never be an interface's address .

Comment: @StephenHarris Okay, sounds like bind is not quite as extensive as I thought it was. I'll try to find an implementation in the kernel to look up.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If the client binds to an arbitrary address that's not its interface's address, then the server will not be able to send a response back, or establish a connection (like TCP), for that matter. Am I right?

Comment: @flow2k Correct, if the client binds to something that isn't 0.0.0.0 nor is an address of any interface, it's unlikely it will be able to communicate with another system. Although something like Linux iptables can programatically rewrite and reroute packets, so anything is possible there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [raw sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) and [packet sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html), they are specifically meant to implement non-standard network protocols in user space.

It's entirely up to you how other applications connect to your driver, and the best choice depends on the details of what you are trying to implement.

The `bind` command does different things in different contexts; usually some variation of "let's provide some default data that is necessary". That *can* mean a specific source address and/or network interface, especially for the standard protocols (which you are not using), but doesn't have to. So it doesn't work the way you think it works.